# Quarto cross-references: persistent cross-references when text changes

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto, cross-reference

I am creating a long PDF report using Quarto. I want to include two formats of cross-reference:

1. To the section/figure number, e.g.

> As discussed in *Section 3.1*

2. To the section/figure title, e.g.

> As discussed in *My awesome section*.

It is possible to achieve either like this:

```md
---
format:   
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
---

# Why Stack Overflow is so great {#sec-stack}

I can use style 1, the section number, with the explicit ID, e.g. as seen in @sec-stack.

I can use style 2, the section title, with a link [Why Stack Overflow is so great].

I can also custom text with [Custom text before the link][Why Stack Overflow is so great].
```

This produces the desired output:

[image]

### Problem

The problem is that the document is being redrafted by several authors. If a section title is changed from *Why Stack Overflow is so great* to *Why I love Stack Overflow*, it breaks the cross-references using the second style (section title).

[image]

I am looking for a way to refer to a section using the [explicit identifier](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#heading-identifiers) `@sec-stack`, and have it display the title instead of the section number. This would be something like `[@sec-stack]` rather than `@sec-stack`.

There are various options in the Quarto cross-referencing [docs](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#references-1). However, I can't see a way to make it so that cross-reference text updates if the section title is updated, provided the explicit identifier remains the same.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) `name_crossref.lua` to get the cross-reference text instead of section/figure/table number. And the following approach works for both HTML and pdf output format.

#### Usage:

1. For section or subsection title, its use is very simple. We just need to use `\nameref{sec-id}` where `sec-id` is the section identifier used in headers as `#sec-id`
2. For images or tables generated from code chunks, we need to use some chunk options. we need to use `link` as code chunk class, need to define an id for cross-referring the image or table later with `link-id`, and need to define a title that will be used as cross-reference text with `link-title`. And then use the id that we have assigned to `link-id` to refer the generated table/image using `\nameref{id}`.
3. For images added with markdown syntax or markdown tables, the use of this filter is a bit hacky. We need to use nested divs (created with pandoc div syntax, `::::` for outer div and `:::` for inner div). In the first div, we have to add the `link` class, `link-id`, `link-title`, and in the second div we need to add another class `cell-output-display`. And similarly, then use the id that we have assigned to `link-id` to refer to the generated table/image using `\nameref{id}`.

````
---
title: "Cross Referencing the Name"
author: Shafee
format: 
  html: default
  pdf: default
number-sections: true
filters: 
  - name_crossref.lua
---

# Why Quarto is so great {#sec-stack}

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`
See \nameref{sec-stack}.

## How it is so {#how}

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`
See \nameref{how}.

## Images

```{r}
#| classes: link
#| link-id: fig1
#| link-title: My Awesome plot

plot(1:10)
```

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`
see \nameref{fig1}

## Tables

```{r}
#| classes: link
#| link-id: tab1
#| link-title: Mtcars Data

head(mtcars)
```

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`
see \nameref{tab1}


# Markdown Images

:::: {.link link-id="fig2" link-title="Scatter plot of mpg"}
::: {.cell-output-display}

![mpg](test-filename/mpg.png)
:::
::::

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(4)`

see \nameref{fig2}


# Markdown Table

:::: {.link link-id="tab2" link-title="Markdown table"}
::: {.cell-output-display}


| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| A    | B    | C    |
| E    | F    | G    |
| A    | G    | G    |

: My Caption

:::
::::

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(4)`

see \nameref{tab2}
````

**name_crossref.lua**

```
local str = pandoc.utils.stringify

function get_header_data(data)
  local get_headers = {
      Header = function(el)
        local id = el.identifier
        local text = str(el.content):gsub("^[%d.]+ ", "")
        table.insert(data, {id = id, text = text})
      end,
      
      Div = function(el)
        if el.attributes["link-id"] then
          local id = el.attributes["link-id"]
          local text = el.attributes["link-title"]
          table.insert(data, {id = id, text = text})
        end
      end
    }
  return get_headers
end

function change_ref(data)
  local change_rawinline = {
    RawInline = function(el)
      for key, value in pairs(data) do
        if el.text:match("\\nameref{(.*)}") == value.id then
          local target =  "#" .. value.id 
          local link = pandoc.Link(value.text, target)
          return link
        end
      end
    end
  }
  return change_rawinline
end

local function add_div_id(div)
  return {
   Div = function(elem)
     if elem.classes:includes("cell-output-display") 
      or elem.classes:includes("cell-output-stdout")then
      elem.identifier = div.attributes["link-id"]
      return elem
     end
  end
  }
end

function Div(el)
  if el.classes:includes('link') then
    return el:walk(add_div_id(el))
  end
end

function Pandoc(doc)
  local header_data = {}
  doc:walk(get_header_data(header_data))
  return doc:walk(change_ref(header_data))
end
```

##### First part of the generated output

[image: First part of the generated output]

Comment: Now the question is, whether it is useful to be a [Quarto filter](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/) ???

Comment: Hi shafee I won't get the chance to try this and accept the answer until later but it looks awesome - thank you. What would the advantage of it being a Quarto filter rather than a Lua script be? It looks easy to include the filter in the yaml.

Comment: Quarto filter is actually based on Lua filter. So not much difference and advantage I think. If you look into the quarto doc you would get the idea :).

Comment: OK I've tried it out for both html and pdf - this is really awesome. I would up-vote twice if I could. Firstly it works perfectly for both formats. Secondly it has opened my eyes to a whole new world of Lua filters. Perhaps you should make this a Quarto filter/extension (still not entirely clear on the difference) so it can go on their website Quarto is still maturing as a technology and I'm sure many would benefit from a filter like this. Plus if the developers see it they might think about making it a core feature.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation, this is a a LaTeX approach based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/get-the-title-instead-of-the-number-of-a-referenced-chapter-section) TeX SE answer.

We load the `nameref` package in the header, and then replace change the Quarto references from `@sec-stack` to `\nameref{sec-stack}`. The reference persists after changing the section title, e.g. to *Why I love Stack Overflow*:

```md
---
format:   
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
header-includes:
 \usepackage{nameref}
---

# Why I love Stack Overflow {#sec-stack}

I can use style 1, the section number, with the explicit ID, e.g. as seen in @sec-stack.

I can use style 2, the section title, with a link \nameref{sec-stack}.
```

[image: However]

The disadvantage is that this is not a native Quarto solution, and will not render to other formats e.g. HTML. However, it works and it's a simple one-off regex replace to change all the references. I have not accepted this answer and if there is a native Quarto answer I will accept that.